# RolesProvider asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roles

Does `public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string userId)` always call to the database on every page load? How do I lower the database calls just to check the roles? Will it cause any security problems if it is cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in a cookie using cacheRolesInCookie.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx